# Unit Testing for iOS in comparison with C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, unit-testing, comparison

Recently I was asked in an interview for the following question,

"What makes special or unique writing unit tests for ios in Objective-c in comparison with c++?"

Obviously I didn't answer it right, but concerned about the correct answer I searched for it but I did not find anything.
Thanks.

Comment: That seems like a very bizarre interview question unless you're specifically going for an Objective-C / C++ role. It's pretty much going to show the interviewer nothing about what you know and what you can do etc... Anyway, I don't know the answer, just wanted to point that out :)

Comment: Agree with you, Thanks